# multiple array with single id do this single array base on id in java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

HI i have a list of multiple array like this

```
jquery([
 {
  id:2,
  count:23,
  numberOfType:34
},
{
  id:2,
  count2:53,
  numberOfType2:34
},
{
  id:2,
  count3:53,
  numberOfType3:34
},
{
  id:2,
  count:23,
  numberOfType:34
},
{
  id:21,
  count2:53,
  numberOfType2:34
},
{
  id:21,
  count3:53,
  numberOfType3:34
},
])
```

and i want to this formate to this data

like is

```
jquery([
  {
  id:2,
  count:23,
  count2:53,
  count3:53,
  numberOfType:34,
  numberOfType2:34,
 numberOfType3:34
},
{
  id:21,
  count:23,
  count2:53,
  count3:53,
  numberOfType:34,
  numberOfType2:34,
 numberOfType3:34
}
])
```

Comment: You want to remove duplicated items! and turn into one array, better say this on question!

Comment: yes but i want to all data duplicated id with in single array

Comment: Wouldn't an array in a property of the object make more sense? eg. `{ id: 2, data: [{ count: 23, type: 34 }, { count: 53, type: 34 }]...`. Also, you appear to have made no effort to achieve this yourself. Remember, we're here to debug code, not to write it for you.

Comment: I have same date with multiple data

Comment: Come on guys, Why down vote?

Comment: @Pedram Because "this question does not show any research effort", the very definition of a downvote. A requirement is not a question, and especially someone with over 20k rep should know that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over the array via [**Array#reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and check the existence. If exists already an item with the current item id, then copy the properties into it via [**Object#assign**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```js
const data = [
   {
      id:2,
      count:23,
      numberOfType:34
   },
   {
      id:2,
      count2:53,
      numberOfType2:34
   },
   {
      id:2,
      count3:53,
      numberOfType3:34
   },
   {
      id:2,
      count:23,
      numberOfType:34
   },
   {
      id:21,
      count2:53,
      numberOfType2:34
   },
   {
      id:21,
      count3:53,
      numberOfType3:34
   }
];

const reduced = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
  
  const found = acc.find(i => i.id === item.id);
  
  if(found) {
     Object.assign(found, item);
  } else {
     acc.push(Object.assign({}, item));
  }
  
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(reduced);
```

Comment: Wow really i want to this like thanks man :)

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `Object.assign` and `Object.values`

```
var output = Object.values( arr.reduce( (a, c) => 
         (a[c.id] = Object.assign( {}, a[c.id], c ), a) ,  //assign new properties to a[c.id]
         {} ) ); //accumulator
```

**Demo**

```js
var arr = [{
    id: 2,
    count: 23,
    numberOfType: 34
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    count2: 53,
    numberOfType2: 34
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    count3: 53,
    numberOfType3: 34
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    count: 23,
    numberOfType: 34
  },
  {
    id: 21,
    count2: 53,
    numberOfType2: 34
  },
  {
    id: 21,
    count3: 53,
    numberOfType3: 34
  },
];
var output = Object.values(arr.reduce((a, c) =>
  (a[c.id] = Object.assign({}, a[c.id], c), a), //assign new properties to a[c.id]
  {})); //accumulator

console.log( output );
```

Comment: Thanks @gurvinder372 really to thanks :)

Comment: @RohitAzad You are welcome. This question was better than your previous one :)..

Answer (score 2):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and group by `id`.

```js
var array = [{ id: 2, count: 23, numberOfType: 34 }, { id: 2, count2: 53, numberOfType2: 34 }, { id: 2, count3: 53, numberOfType3: 34 }, { id: 2, count: 23, numberOfType: 34 }, { id: 21, count2: 53, numberOfType2: 34 }, { id: 21, count3: 53, numberOfType3: 34 }],
    result = [
        ...array
            .reduce((m, o) => m.set(o.id, Object.assign(m.get(o.id) || {}, o)), new Map)
            .values()
    ];

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks @Nina Scholz give me answer

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `reduce` and check if the id is present in the accumulator else append it

```js
const arr = [
 {
  id:2,
  count:23,
  numberOfType:34
},
{
  id:2,
  count2:53,
  numberOfType2:34
},
{
  id:2,
  count3:53,
  numberOfType3:34
},
{
  id:2,
  count:23,
  numberOfType:34
},
{
  id:21,
  count2:53,
  numberOfType2:34
},
{
  id:21,
  count3:53,
  numberOfType3:34
},
]

const newArr = arr.reduce((acc, newObj) => {
   let index = acc.findIndex(obj => obj.id === newObj.id);
   if(index > -1) {
      acc = [...acc.slice(0, index), {...acc[index], ...newObj}, ...acc.slice(index + 1)]
   }
   else {
      acc.push(newObj);
   }
   return acc
}, [])
console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: Thanks @Shubham Khatri :)